# Adding a Scrollbar pushes Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 3 with their admin dashboard template. However, the layout changes when there's enough information in the container-fluid since the scrollbar appears, and pushes the rest of the layout to the left depending on the width of the scrollbar.

Is there a way to make the scrollbar on the left so it is floating on top of the layout? Because there could be frequent changes content, and the scrollbar will push items left and right.

Figure 1: A Admin Dashboard Template with Scrollbar

[image]

Figure 2: A Admin Dashboard without a Scrollbar

[image]

This is the html code:

```
<body>
    <!-- Load javascripts -->
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'WebApp/jquery-2.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'WebApp/index.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'WebApp/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'WebApp/flot/jquery.flot.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Top Navigation Bar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebStats</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#">Views</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shared</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Middle Navigation Area -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li><a href="">SSF</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SSX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">MOW</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li><a href="">Question</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">LiveUpdate Toggle</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>

                <!-- Tab Panes -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Block Name 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Block Name 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Block Name 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Add Block</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Tab Contents -->
                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab_1">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function() {

                                var sin = [],
                                    cos = [];

                                for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) 
                                {
                                    sin.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
                                    cos.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);
                                }

                                var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", 
                                [
                                    { data: sin, label: "sin(x)"},
                                    { data: cos, label: "cos(x)"}
                                ]
                                , 
                                {
                                    series: 
                                    {
                                        lines: 
                                        {
                                            show: true
                                        },
                                        points: 
                                        {
                                            show: true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    grid:
                                    {
                                        hoverable: true,
                                        clickable: true
                                    },
                                    yaxis: 
                                    {
                                        min: -1.2,
                                        max: 1.2
                                    }
                                });

                                $("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
                                    position: "absolute",
                                    display: "none",
                                    border: "1px solid #fdd",
                                    padding: "2px",
                                    "background-color": "#fee",
                                    opacity: 0.80
                                }).appendTo("body");

                                $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) 
                                {

                                    if ($("#enablePosition:checked").length > 0) 
                                    {
                                        var str = "(" + pos.x.toFixed(2) + ", " + pos.y.toFixed(2) + ")";
                                        $("#hoverdata").text(str);
                                    }

                                    if ($("#enableTooltip:checked").length > 0) 
                                    {
                                        if (item) 
                                        {
                                            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                                                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                                            $("#tooltip").html(item.series.label + " of " + x + " = " + y)
                                                .css({top: item.pageY+5, left: item.pageX+5})
                                                .fadeIn(200);
                                        } 
                                        else 
                                        {
                                            $("#tooltip").hide();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                $("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) 
                                {
                                    if (item) 
                                    {
                                        $("#clickdata").text(" - click point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label);
                                        plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
                                    }
                                });

                                // Add the Flot version string to the footer

                                $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
                            });
                        </script>

                        <!-- Graph -->
                        <h2 class="sub-header">Graph
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Hide</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">PDF</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">CSV</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Share</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Config</button>
                        </h2>

                        <div id="content">
                            <div class="demo-container">
                                <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <h2 class="sub-header">Chart
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Hide</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">PDF</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">CSV</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Share</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Config</button>
                        </h2>

                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Header</th>
                                        <th>Header</th>
                                        <th>Header</th>
                                        <th>Header</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,001</td>
                                        <td>Lorem</td>
                                        <td>ipsum</td>
                                        <td>dolor</td>
                                        <td>sit</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,002</td>
                                        <td>amet</td>
                                        <td>consectetur</td>
                                        <td>adipiscing</td>
                                        <td>elit</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,003</td>
                                        <td>Integer</td>
                                        <td>nec</td>
                                        <td>odio</td>
                                        <td>Praesent</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,003</td>
                                        <td>libero</td>
                                        <td>Sed</td>
                                        <td>cursus</td>
                                        <td>ante</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,004</td>
                                        <td>dapibus</td>
                                        <td>diam</td>
                                        <td>Sed</td>
                                        <td>nisi</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,005</td>
                                        <td>Nulla</td>
                                        <td>quis</td>
                                        <td>sem</td>
                                        <td>at</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,006</td>
                                        <td>nibh</td>
                                        <td>elementum</td>
                                        <td>imperdiet</td>
                                        <td>Duis</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,007</td>
                                        <td>sagittis</td>
                                        <td>ipsum</td>
                                        <td>Praesent</td>
                                        <td>mauris</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,008</td>
                                        <td>Fusce</td>
                                        <td>nec</td>
                                        <td>tellus</td>
                                        <td>sed</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,009</td>
                                        <td>augue</td>
                                        <td>semper</td>
                                        <td>porta</td>
                                        <td>Mauris</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,010</td>
                                        <td>massa</td>
                                        <td>Vestibulum</td>
                                        <td>lacinia</td>
                                        <td>arcu</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,011</td>
                                        <td>eget</td>
                                        <td>nulla</td>
                                        <td>Class</td>
                                        <td>aptent</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,012</td>
                                        <td>taciti</td>
                                        <td>sociosqu</td>
                                        <td>ad</td>
                                        <td>litora</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,013</td>
                                        <td>torquent</td>
                                        <td>per</td>
                                        <td>conubia</td>
                                        <td>nostra</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,014</td>
                                        <td>per</td>
                                        <td>inceptos</td>
                                        <td>himenaeos</td>
                                        <td>Curabitur</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1,015</td>
                                        <td>sodales</td>
                                        <td>ligula</td>
                                        <td>in</td>
                                        <td>libero</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab_2">
                        <p> something is here </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab_3">
                        <p> something is here 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know there is no way to float a browser native scrollbar on top of the content.

A workaround could be to show the scrollbar all the time. That will prevent the jumbing efect. You can do this with simple css:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```